# Read data from Oracle DB through Spark (pySpark)

Tags: python, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the data using pySpark and writing on to HDFS from Oracle Database. I am trying two different methods:

**Method 1**: Using simple plain query with no numPartitions and related parameter.

```py
query = "(select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022') myTable"
df = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
     .option('driver', 'driver_name')\
     .option('dbtable', query)\
     .option('user', 'user_name')\
     .option('password', 'pwd')\
     .load()

df.write.partitionBy("partitionCol").mode('overwrite') \
  .format('parquet').saveAsTable(db_name.table_name)
```

In Spark UI, I am able to see total ~110 million rows as output.

**Method 2:** Using the numPartition, partitionColumn, lowerBound and upperBound parameter to parallelise the data read. I am selecting lowerBound as minimum value of the ID in the query range and upperBound as maximum value of the ID in the query range. ID is also a primary key and is indexed.

```py
query = "(select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022') myTable"
df = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
     .option('driver', 'driver_name')\
     .option('dbtable', query)\
     .option('numPartitions', 10)\
     .option('partitionColumn', 'id')\
     .option('lowerBound', <min_value>)\
     .option('upperBound', <max_value>)\
     .option('user', 'user_name')\
     .option('password', 'pwd')\
     .load()

df.write.partitionBy("partitionCol").mode('overwrite') \
  .format('parquet').saveAsTable(db_name.table_name)
```

In Spark UI I can see more than the total rows as output using **Method 1**.

I have verified the counts in the Oracle DB also and it should match the rows as in **Method 1**.

I am not sure where the difference is coming from or is there any error in my **Method 2**.

Answer (score 0):

##### First method

translates to Spark running this query on your DB:
`select * from (select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022') myTable)`

##### Second method.

Lets assume there are 1000 rows with value of `id` ranging from 1 to 1000. Then expectation is you'll pass 1 as `lowerBound` and 1000 as `uperBound`. Spark will run following queries in parallel and construct a daataframe partitioned on `id` column.

- `select * from (select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022') myTable) where id > 0 and id <= 100`
- `select * from (select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022') myTable) where id > 100 and id <= 200`
- ... 7 other queries ...
- `select * from (select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022') myTable) where id > 900 and id <= 1000`

---

1. Use `query` option instead of `dbtable`

```py
query = "select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022'"
df = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
     .option('driver', 'driver_name')\
     .option('query', query)\
     .option('user', 'user_name')\
     .option('password', 'pwd')\
     .load()

df.write.partitionBy("partitionCol").mode('overwrite') \
  .format('parquet').saveAsTable(db_name.table_name)
```

this will translate to spark running `select * from table_name where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022'` on your DB.

2. In theory you should get the same number of rows in both cases. Reasons why you might get different are:

- These two queries return different counts:

  - `select count(*) from my_table where where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022'`
  - `select count(*) from my_table where where eff_dt between '01SEP2022' AND '30SEP2022' AND id between <min_value> AND <max_value>`
- DB is updated between the times when you executed method 1 and method 2.
- Check the documentation to confirm whether the lower and upper bound values are inclusive or exclusive. Though this would make a different of at most 2 rows if you got it wrong.